# Vue deep selector not working with vuetify activator slots

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to pass additional style to the activator element of a v-tooltip from the parent component. I thought this would be possible with the Vue's deep selector.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68980128/vue-passing-inline-css-style-to-child-component) question on SO but the answer doesn't explain why deep selector is not working in this case.

In the following example the style defined in `Parent` affects v-btn in `MyBtn1` but not in `MyBtn2`.
Shouldn't all child elements be affected of the style regardless of how nested the component is?
Can someone explain why and where the difference is?
How can I effectively style a component in an activator slot from the parent?

### Parent1

```
<template>
  <MyBtn1 />
</template>

<style scoped>
>>> .my-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.5em;
  left: 0.5em;
}
</style>
```

### MyBtn1

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-btn class="my-btn"> btnText </v-btn>
  </div>
</template>
```

### Parent2

```
<template>
  <MyBtn2 />
</template>

<style scoped>
>>> .my-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.5em;
  left: 0.5em;
}
</style>
```

### MyBtn2

```
<template>
  <v-tooltip top>
    <template #activator="{ on, attrs }">
      <v-btn v-bind="attrs" class="my-btn" v-on="on"> btnText </v-btn>
    </template>
    tooltipText
  </v-tooltip>
</template>
```

Comment: What do you see in your devtools, in the DOM?

Comment: I tried to replicate your issue in this codesandbox but it's working properly, what version of vuetify are you using? https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-73321247-scoped-with-deep-css-0id4hl?file=/src/components/TestScoped.vue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like for deep selector to work the class needs to be wrapped in another div.

So this works:

#### Parent1

```
<template>
  <MyBtn1 />
</template>

<style scoped>
* >>> .my-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.5em;
  left: 0.5em;
}
</style>
```

#### MyBtn1

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-btn class="my-btn"> btnText </v-btn>
  </div>
</template>
```

This doesn't work:

#### Parent2

```
<template>
  <MyBtn2 />
</template>

<style scoped>
* >>> .my-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.5em;
  left: 0.5em;
}
</style>
```

#### MyBtn2

```
<template>
  <v-btn class="my-btn"> btnText </v-btn>
</template>
```

So neither does this work:

#### Parent3

```
<template>
  <MyBtn3 />
</template>

<style scoped>
* >>> .my-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.5em;
  left: 0.5em;
}
</style>
```

#### MyBtn3

```
<template>
  <v-tooltip top>
    <template #activator="{ on, attrs }">
      <v-btn v-bind="attrs" class="my-btn" v-on="on"> btnText </v-btn>
    </template>
    tooltipText
  </v-tooltip>
</template>
```

I reproduced it in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-73321247-scoped-with-deep-css-forked-hpso1y?file=/src/components/MyBtn2.vue) derived from the one in cmfc31's comment.

I also had a syntax error in my deep selector where the selector before the deep selector was missing:

```
<style scoped>
// This works...
* >>> .my-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.5em;
  left: 0.5em;
}
// ...this doesn't
>>> .my-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.5em;
  left: 0.5em;
}
</style>
```